# How is whonix blocking UDP traffic (except udp-dns related traffic)?

Tags: iptables, whonix

I want to know how whonix manages to block unwanted UDP-Traffic i.e. all UDP-traffic but DNS related udp traffic. I looked at the iptable rules both in the Workstation and Gateway. There are no iptable rules in the Workstation. So the Workstation doesn't seem to block UDP-Traffic. However, there are many ip-table rules in the Gateway.

I went through the iptable rules of the Gateway one-by-one but I couldn't find any udp-related blocking rule either.

So, how is this udp-traffic blocked?

Answer (score 2):

Answering this from perspective of Whonix 8. Links point to Whonix 8 source code.

---

Generally Whonix's firewalls are white listing firewalls. This means, they use policy drop for all chains (input, forward, output) and a drop or reject rule as last rule. All traffic that is not explicitly white listed will be dropped or rejected (depending on chain).

---

Whonix-Workstation firewall is unrelated here. It's an non-mandatory optional firewall, that is disabled by default. See its [man page](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix/blob/Whonix8/man/whonix_workstation/whonix_firewall.8.ronn) for deeper explanation.

If you were to use it, the following rule with enforce, that only `TCP` can leave.

```
## The next rule ensures, that only tcp can leave and achieves the desired result from (4).
iptables -A OUTPUT ! -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Generally speaking, `-p tcp` would mean "only `TCP`". And `! -p tcp` here means all protocols besides `TCP`.

---

[Whonix-Gateway firewall](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix/blob/Whonix8/whonix_gateway/usr/bin/whonix_firewall) is the mandatory important piece here.

It white lists traffic `UDP` traffic to port `53` (`DNS`) and redirects it to Tor's `DnsPort`. Search the firewall script for `-p udp --dport 53` to see the related rules. Other traffic it white lists and redirects is `TCP`. Rest is blocked thanks to policy drop (as safety net) and/or dropped/rejected by last rule (depending on chain).

---

Depending on chain... Before someone asks what I mean by that.

- INPUT: dropped
- FORWARD: rejected
- OUTPUT: rejected

---

Full disclosure: 
I am a maintainer of Whonix.

Comment: As I understand ip-tables of Whonix 8 if I send a PING to the public address space (The same should be valid for a UDP-Request) from the workstation to some arbitrary host (I tested this) then it should go to the FORWARD-Chain of the Gateway. There are no dropping rules in the PREROUTIING-Chain of the Gateway. So any packet that should be dropped should logically be dropped or rejected in the FILTER-Table of the Gateway. But I didn't see any increase in the REJECT-Packet counters of filter table nor did I see an increase in the individual drop-rules of the filter table. What am I missing?